# Multidex And Singleton Class Uses android:name In The Manifest Application Tag

Tags: android, singleton, android-manifest, dalvik, android-multidex

I have an application, and I used `Singleton`. And I just got  [64k](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) error. And I solve it, by compiling the dependencies and in the gradle - `multiDexEnabled true`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="app.project.SingletonController"
    >

<!--android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"-->
```

Yet it says [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) in the same link, that in should be included in the `Manifest` -> `<application android:name = ">` *The one that I commented above.*

How do I get rid of this one?

The `android:name=""` will be duplicate and will produce error if I place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already defining a custom application class `SingletonController` for your app.

`MultiDexApplication` is a simple utility class which you could use as super class for your own `SingletonController`. If for some reason this is not possible, you have to implement the functionality yourself

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: So I will `@Override` this one in my `SingletonController` ? Only? Not Applicable to other `Activity` ?

Comment: `SingletonController` shoud extend `Application` directly or indirectly. If it's directly just extend `MultiDexApplication` instead. Otherwise call this `MultiDex.install(this)`. That's it for your problem here.

Comment: I already `@Override ` that one in my `SingletonController` . Thank you. Is this also `Overridable ` aside from `SingletonController` class like `MainActivity` ?

Comment: No, only in the `Application`. It's a setup for the classloader on older versions. Every activity then uses it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> Since December 3rd, 2014, build tools 1.0.0-rc1 was released. Now, all you need to do is modify your build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
```

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

> If you are running unit tests, you will want to include this in your Application class:

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already done with those steps as what their docs said. What make me confuse is in the `Manifest` part. :)